# CSS defining a class

Tags: html, css

I tried (HTML Page)

```
 <div class="cities">
<h6>London</h6>
<p>
London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.
</p>
</div>
```

CSS Page

```
p.cities {
background-color:black;
color:white;
margin:20px;
padding:20px;
```

}

Could I get help defining a class in CSS? I have seem to run into a mental wall. I cant wrap my head around this concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `p.cities`. You want `div.cities`

Your element is a `<div>`, not a `<p>`

Answer (score 1):

```
div.cities {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    margin:20px;
    padding:20px;
}
```

You used wrong element.

Answer (score 0):

your css file selector should be like this

```
.cities {
  background-color:black;
}
```

or

```
div.cities {
  background-color:black;
}
```

if you use `<p class="cities">` your code is correct. But I think you want to design your div tag to change your code like above